# Riesz Representation Theorem, true for pre-Hilbert spaces and any functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I have some doubts about the Riesz theorem.
Firstly can you check my proof?

Fa = for all

Fa (**H**,**<,>**) a pre Hilbert space

Fa **x** in H different from the zero vector

Fa **F** a functional on H

Fa **T**: (H->R) -> H : **T**(F) = F(x) x/||x||^2 a map from a functional on H to H

Then F(x) = F(x) < x, x > / ||x||^2 = < F(x) x/||x||^2, x > = < T(F), x >

End of proof, where F(x) = < T(F), x > for any vector x in a pre Hilbert space.

If my proof is correct, it implies that H doesn’t have to be an Hilbert space but only a pre Hilbert one and that the functional doesn’t have to be neither linear and continuous, but only a functional.

Is it true or I’m missing something?

Comment: The  conclusion of the Riesz representation theorem is FALSE  if the space is not complete or the functional is discontinuous.

Comment: I know, but in my attempt of proving it I never used these facts. I would to know if my proof is not exactly true or if riesz assumptions can be weakened.

Comment: As I said above, Riesz assumptions cannot be weakened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Riesz Representation theorem is:

$$\forall F \in H^*, \exists y \in H, \forall x \in H, F(x) = \langle y, x\rangle$$

What you have shown is

$$\forall F \in H^*, \forall x \in H, \exists y \in H, F(x) = \langle y, x\rangle$$

$y$ or $T(F)$ in the Riesz Representation theorem is picked knowing only $F$, not $x$. This single value of $y$ must work for every $x$. In your result, you pick $x$ first, and then define $T(F)$ in terms of it. Thus your $y$ changes from one value of $x$ to another.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see. Linearity, continuity and completeness are necessary to extend my result to the one by Riesz.